# Symfony загрузить на хостинг

Tags: symfony

Загружаю Symfony проект на хостинг. Все папки и файлы закинул в папку `public_html`. Пытаюсь зайти на `http://j984149z.bget.ru/web/main` получаю 404. Пытаюсь зайти на `http://j984149z.bget.ru/web/app_dev.php/main` получаю `You are not allowed to access this file. Check app_dev.php for more information.` Может после загрузки нужно было еще что-то сделать, файлы какие-нибудь изменить (не считая файла app/config/parametrs.yml там я изменил данные для БД на хостинге) ?

Comment: apache на web должен смотреть и composer install сделать нужно

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, apache на web "должен смотреть".

Comment: DocumentRoot /home/USER/www/mag/web/

Comment: В общем хотел композер запустить, но как я только через терминал по ssh подключаюсь - меня сразу же отключает. Отредактировал `app_dev.php`, теперь `web/app_dev.php/main` работает. Но это ж для разработки - хотелось чтоб и на app.php работало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У BeGet на бесплатном варианте ssh отключен.

По пробуйте следующее

- Сделайте back-up проекта
- У себя локально в `composer.json` заменить `"symfony-web-dir": "web"` на `"symfony-web-dir": "public_html"`
- папку `web` переименовать в `public_html`.
- Далее запустите `composer update`
- локальное содержимое `public_html` кидаете по `ftp` в `public_html` на сервере
- остальное(app, src и тд) кидаете рядом с `public_html`

Answer (score 0):

перешел на сайт. много нотисоф, похоже .htaccess даже не представляете что это... работает вроде все относительно сносно под опенкарт. возможно вопрос уже не актуален.

```
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^j984149z\.bget\.ru
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.j984149z.bget.ru/web/app_dev.php/$1 [R=301,L]
```

либо создав виртуальную папку, отдельно чтобы загрузив ваш сайт пользователю открывалась папка с симфони а не с 
/home/j/j984149z/j984149z.bget.ru/public_html/*
где * - это ваша папка на текущий момент

либо алиас:
Alias /site2 /home/j/j984149z/j984149z.bget.ru/public_html/web/app_dev.php/

либо в настройке хостинга(если таковые имеются)

вобщем вариантов много, пробуйте !